# Updating Entity in Struts2 Action

Tags: hibernate, jpa, struts2

I am trying to load a collection of entities in a Struts2 Action and then save any changes made via form submit. I am using the `paramsPrepareParams` stack and am running into issues when submitting a form.

I've added code below that shows how I have things setup. The issue is whenever I try to modify 1 of the dropdowns to update an `entity2` field on 1 of the `entity1` entities the rest of the entities end up with the same value even though I did not change them.

Ironically, if I change the `prepare` method to load the `Entity1` objects in `entity1List` individually using `getEntityManager().find(...)`, things work as expected

Can anyone offer any assistance? I am using Struts2/Hibernate/JPA

Entity1:

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 {

    private Integer id;
    private Entity2 entity2;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name ="ID")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_2_REF", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    public Entity2 getEntity2() {
        return entity2;
    }

    public void setEntity2(Entity2 entity2) {
        this.entity2 = entity2;
    }
}
```

Entity2:

```
@Entity
public class Entity2 {

    private Integer id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name ="ID")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

TestAction:

```
public class TestAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {

    private List<Entity1> entity1List;
    private Map<Integer, String> entity2Options;

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        if (savingData) {
            TypedQuery<Entity1> query = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT a FROM Entity1 a", Entity1.class);
            entity1List = query.getResultList();
        }
    }

    public String execute() {
        if(viewingData) {
            TypedQuery<Entity1> query = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT a FROM Entity1 a", Entity1.class);
            entity1List = query.getResultList();
            return "success";
        } else if (savingData) {
            beginTransaction();
            for(Entity1 e1 : entity1List) {
                getEntityManager().merge(e1);
            }
            commit();

            return "redirect";
        }

        return "success";
    }

    public Map<Integer, String> getEntity2Options() {
        Map<Integer, String> m = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        m.put(1, "Test 1");
        m.put(2, "Test 2");
        m.put(3, "Test 3");
        return m;
    }

    public List<Entity1> getEntity1List() {
        return entity1List;
    }

    public void setEntity1List(List<Entity1> entity1List) {
        this.entity1List = entity1List;
    }
}
```

Test.jsp:

```
<s:form>
    <s:iterator value="entity1List" status="status">
        <s:select name="entity1List[%{#status.index}].entity2.id" list="entity2Options" theme="simple"/>
    </s:iterator>
</s:form>
```